# How can I use NASM to produce relocations in the style of Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am attemping to create an object file with NASM that is as close as possible as to that produced by Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I have gotten pretty close but I am struggling with imports and relocations.

Specifically, when I create an object file with `cl.exe` and do `dumpbin /all binary.obj`, I get the following line of interest:

```
Offset     Type     Applied To     Symbol Index   Symbol Name
--------   -------  ----------     ------------   -----------
00000007   DIR32      00000000               B    __imp__GetModuleHandleA@4
```

But when I do `dumpbin /all nasmobj.obj`, I get a similar, but slightly different line:

```
Offset     Type     Applied To     Symbol Index   Symbol Name
--------   -------  ----------     ------------   -----------
00000007   REL32      00000000               7    __imp__GetModuleHandleA@4
```

So the difference is that MSVC produces relocations that are "direct" relocations, where as my NASM code produces "relative" relocations. How can I fix this?

I am compiling my NASM code with:

```
nasm -f win32 nasmtst.s
```

And the NASM code of interest is:

```
SECTION .text
EXTERN __imp__GetModuleHandleA@4
%define GetModuleHandleA (__imp__GetModuleHandleA@4)

; code happens
...
call GetModuleHandleA
...
; more code happens
```

Comment: I would guess that removing the `__imp_` might help, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I also tried that to no avail unfortunately :( I'm getting closer to thinking this is just something NASM can't do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `__imp__GetModuleHandleA@4` is an import *pointer*, not the actual code location of the GetModuleHandleA function. Win32 PEs generally have an .idata section with all the import pointers collected which is somewhat similar to ELF's GOT table:

```
SECTION .idata
   __imp__GetModuleHandleA@4 dd ? ; to be filled by system loader
```

This section and all supporting metadata is usually generated by the linker using the import library but it's possible to [generate it manually](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/source/browse/trunk/src/PE/imports.asm) too.

In your case, the following should be enough:

```
EXTERN __imp__GetModuleHandleA@4 
call [__imp__GetModuleHandleA@4]
```

With some assemblers/macro packages it's possible to use something similar to:

```
call GetModuleHandleA
```

or

```
invoke GetModuleHandleA, eax
```

which would result in a call to the linker-generated stub:

```
GetModuleHandleA:
   jmp [__imp__GetModuleHandleA@4]
```

The advantage of this approach is that there's only one relocation to be patched (for the `jmp` instruction) instead of possibly several (`call` ones).

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy!